# Allow to get POST data from outter server YII2

Tags: yii2, cross-server

i want to make a `yii2` route which can receive POST data from other server (of course i know about all risk).

I tried to just send it like usual but i got this error message.

```
Error 400

Unable to verify your data submission.
```

more or less is just like this...

```
public function actionWriteSession()
{   
    if (isset($_POST))
    {
        print_r($_POST);
        ...
        write to session
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Any Advice?

Thanks..

Comment: will you provide more information what you want , with your code.

Comment: Yes, the ebst advise, please provide some code before asking

Comment: you should disable csrf verification from your controller like  $this->enableCsrfValidation=false;

Comment: Nuriddin Rashidov, thankyou verymuch,..
it works..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should disbale csrf verification E.g:

```
$this->enableCsrfValidation=false;//In your controller context

// Or if you only use this action for sending post from outer server
// you can disbalecsrf token verification only this action. So, in your controller

public function beforeAction($action)
{            
    if ($action->id == 'writeSession') {
        Yii::$app->controller->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```